# What is preventing me from selecting content in ng-grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm working on a reporting UI, and i'm using [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/). You can see in this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PHdBhF?p=preview) the behaviour I'm talking about. ( when you click/select the word filter, it works, when you try to select the data, it doesn't )

NG-Grid has this css "selected" class that gets added to a row when it is selected. To me this is fake-selection, and not the selection I need. I need to be able to select the content inside the grid, just like you could double click the words I'm typing right now and select them. I could come up with a hacky solution similar to [this jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/du31ufts/6/), (don't look too deep into this jsfiddle, it was about another issue). I'd rather be able to click near the top left, drag to the bottom right and select everything so I can copy-paste the data for emails etc.

So is there a css property making the divs unselectable? or is it the fact that the `div`s are clickable for selection and sorting, so it can't pick up the clicks?

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me. Can you explain the issue more clearly?

Comment: @elzi, When you "select" the data from the ng-grid, it only adds a blue background color to the element, it's not actually selected, therefore, you couldn't click to select a row and CTRL+C & CTRL+V

Comment: Ah.. I see. Look into [getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getSelection) and [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)

Comment: Thanks, @elzi.. A better example is here http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/109_multiple_grids.. only the headers aren't selectable - why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ng-grid's default `enableHighlighting` setting is false, which means an `unselectable` CSS class gets applied to the grid. This class has a `user-select` rule applied that prevents selection.

```
.ngGrid.unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

The second example you [linked](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/109_multiple_grids) (where only the headers are unselectable) is UI-Grid, a rewrite of ng-grid, so the default behaviours will not necessarily match.

Comment: But, there is still content that is unselectable: the column headers

Comment: I could replace the word none, in the user-select property, with _____ + !important (?)

Comment: The column headers have some hardcoded behaviour that adds `draggable="true"` attribute, preventing highlighting (check out the ng-grid source code). If you need more flexible headers, it's probably time to move to UI-Grid where it's much easier to define custom headers: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/302_custom_header

Comment: rather than overriding ng-grid's CSS, it's cleaner to just set the `enableHighlighting` setting to true for your grid. Is there something that prevents you from doing this?

Comment: enableHighlighting works. However, it doesn't work on the headers, so if I tried to copy paste the data I could only select the data without headers. I know about CSV export but I really need to be able to select everything including headers for copying and pasting. UI grid has the same no-highlighting of headers issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add enableHighlighting:true to your grid config.

`var gridConfig = {
...
    enableHighlighting: true, // Allow to select grid content
    footerTemplate: 'modules/grid-footer.html',
    sortInfo: {
        fields: ["name"],
        directions: ["ASC"]
    },
    useExternalSorting: true,
...
}`